# Converting Timestamp to Month & Year

Tags: timestamp, teradata

I have a timestamp in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS and I want to convert it in the format JAN-2020,FEB-2020 etc  and order it from Jan to Dec.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Try `to_char(tscol, 'MON-YYYY')` plus `order by extract(year from tscol), extract(month from tscol)`

Comment: Not working as order by columns are not available in select list of group by query

Comment: You didn't mention aggregation, use `order by extract(year from max(tscol)), extract(month from max(tscol))`

Comment: Sorry I missed to mention aggregate. Thanks its perfect!